# Actionmailer - how can I set up "from" part?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

This is my config file in `/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "...something...",  
  :user_name            => "my_gmail_name",  
  :password             => "my_gmail_pass",
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

And this is the `Mailer's` class with method I use:

```
class Notifierpass < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "no-reply@my-domain.com"

  def forgot_password(user)    
    @reset_password_link = reset_password_url(user.perishable_token)

    mail(:from => "no-reply@my-domain.com", :to => user.email, :subject => "New passwordt")  
  end
end
```

The sending emails is working, my problem is, that in the email's field **From** is always **my_user_name** instead **no-reply@my-domain.com**.

Where is the problem? Why is still used my gmail name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail will only let you send emails from your account, or other email addresses you have correctly configured. To send from an alternative email address you need to add it in the Gmail settings. You can only add addresses that you can already receive from.

Comment: sorry dude I just saw you where first with the same explanation therefor +1

Answer (score 0):

When you make a connection to the smtp server of gmail (like in your config) the authentication_information is already assigned because you will send an email using a certain user_id wich has a known email address. therefor google will not accept any :from => "value" but it will fit the :from parameter with the email returned by the auth_info.

Hope this helped you